# TabBar items localization

Tags: ios, tabbar

To localize my tab bar items I have, in my AppDelegate, this code:

```
self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Home", nil)];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Requests", nil)];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Account", nil)];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Alarms", nil)];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil)];
```

Now I've added another item and tried to add a new line with index = 5, but I get an "NSRangeException" because the index 5 is beyond bounds.
Xcode added automatically the "More" section and moved my last two items (Settings and the new one) in there.
I've also seen that the user can now customize the tab bar choosing the items order.
So now how can I refer to all the items and localize them?
Note: I'm using storyboards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for me was to implement the **awakeFromNib** method, this will run even when using tabs.

```
// Objective-C
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"YOUR-LOCALISATION-TAG", @"");
}


// Swift
override  func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("YOUR-LOCALISATION-TAG", comment: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To localize first translate the text into which language you need to translate.
There is no separation foe normal localization and tabBarItem.

the text  given into the corresponding language localized String.

```
"Home"="translate text";
"Requests"="translate text";
"Account"="translate text";
"Alarms"="translate text";
"Settings"="translate text";
```

For set title for TabbarButton set here . It will have to implement in implementation Class

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
   // set title here
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: I know that Vineesh TP, that's not the problem. The problem is that if I add a new tabbar item with index = 5, I get an NSRangeException error. Or do you mean that I don't even need the setTitle?

Comment: did u take tabbar Application right? , The barbutton title given not in Applicatio Delegate Class. it will have to given in your implemetation class

Comment: I know. I've put it in the AppDelegate because we the app starts up, it checks for something and sets the badges on some of the tab bar items.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think adding that many tab bar items is a good practice since there're not enough space for user to even touch each item. Putting the correspondingly trivial items into one **"MORE"** bar item would be better. Bad for you but good for better user experience. Well if you do have that requirement, you could make a customized UIView as your tab bar(which is, of course, not a real tab bar) and put whatever you want into it.